# Apache mod_rewrite match number before matching anything else

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this situation where I need to first match numbers before matching anything else (other parameters containing characters), but the rule I am using doesn't work and breaks my page, even though I'm being specific that it should match numbers only first (`[0-9]+`)

So for example, this is what has priority:

```
http://example.com/page/1
```

Before this:

```
http://example.com/page/create
```

The first one would obviously use other parameters than the second. Without rewriting anything it would probably look like this:

```
http://example.com/page.php?action=show&id=1
```

and

```
http://example.com/page.php?action=create
```

So from the rewritten perspective, the URLs look quite alike, but not when used with parameters.

---

**So in my real situation, I have these rules:**

```
RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([0-9]+)$ page.php?uri=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ page.php?uri=$1&action=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ page.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But when I put them in that very particular order, it always matches the first rewrite, even though I do not include numbers.

So basically, I need to make sure that when the URI contains a number, I need it to rewrite to something else (`id=`) and if it has anything else beside numbers, it should rewrite to `action=`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How is `/page/` becoming `action=show` OR `action=create` in internal URL?

Comment: Edited it to make it less confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1.php?action=show&id=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?action=$2 [QSA,L]
```